# Unexpected output while reading from file

Tags: c++, file

I am using code from cplusplus.com, which is opening file, reading info from it, print it, and then close it. So, here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>     // std::cin, std::cout
#include <fstream>      // std::ifstream

int main () {
  char str[256];

  std::cout << "Enter the name of an existing text file: ";
  std::cin.get (str,256);    // get c-string

  std::ifstream is(str);     // open file

  while (is.good())          // loop while extraction from file is possible
  {
    char c = is.get();       // get character from file
    if (is.good())
      std::cout << c;
  }

  is.close();                // close file

  return 0;
}
```

So, file with this code is called "prog.cpp", and saved in Documents/Test folder. In the same folder I have text file, called "hello.txt", which consists of following:

```
hello to everyone
```

So, after I run my program, expected outcome is "hello everyone", but I have:

```
hsdhs131313dhhsd
```

So, there is no other files. Where is the mistake? What have I done wrong? Using mac os x.
Here is the screenshot of termianl window, sublime text window and finder. Thanks in advance for help[image: screen]

Comment: `hello.cpp` or `hello.txt`?

Comment: hello.txt, sorry. Edited.

Comment: This code works for me.

Comment: That code is needlessly complicated. Use `std::string` and `std::getline` instead of a character array. Use `while (is.get(c))` instead of duplicating the success check. There's no need to close the file explicitly unless you actually want to make sure it closes correctly.

Comment: The file will be found in your current directory, not the directory containing the program.

Comment: Works fine for me: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9d7d10a8b9ab450f

Comment: So it's reading `~/hello.txt`, not `/Users/ratkke/Documents/Test/prog/hello.txt`

Comment: Wow! @Barmar is right. But I don't understand, why is he reading that hello.txt? How can I change this code, so the program will work as expected?

Comment: When you enter a filename without a directory, it's interpreted relative to your working directory.

Comment: That's the expected behavior. Otherwise, `cat filename` would mean `cat /usr/bin/filename`, because it would look in the directory where `cat` is located.

Comment: @chris: Added your changes to his code: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f91c767bb28b4ffc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the program asks for the name of a file, enter the full path:

```
Enter the name of an existing text file: /Users/ratkke/Documents/Test/prog/hello.txt
```

Comment: ... or enter the relative path but run your program _from the correct directory_.